# Uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, uninstallation

I am fighting with Microsoft to uninstall all my instances of SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my physical PC. I have identified three of them, but am only able to full uninstall one. When I try to uninstall other instances, on the "Select Features"  tab of the Uninstall program, I see no features related with it and cannot proceed. For sure there are two instances left on my PC that I can't get rid of. 
I have already tried installing SQL Server again and uninstalling it, but that does not help.

The two instance I cannot uninstall were installed by an application I no loger use and have uninstalled it long time ago.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Don't fight please. Have you tried to uninstall it from 'Program and Features'?

Comment: Try using the instructions from [here] (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3974daa9-9da1-46d9-8001-57b8517d3470/how-to-uninstall-properly-sql-server-2008-?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried uninstalling it with "Programs & Features" with no luck. In the meantime I managed to find the original installation media. It seems, all the time I used x64 version instead of x86 (the original installation). I finally managed to uninstall it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use the original install media (important if x64 or x86). With it, it's possible to remove all the instances.